# Unable to handle sql exception related to CHECK contriant

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I'm writing a desktop application using C# win forms and MSSQL server. in my database i have a table like this :

```
create table material(
id int identity(700,3),
materialName nvarchar(100) not null default (0),
unitPrice decimal(19,2) not null default (0),
carbohydrate tinyint not null default (0),
protein tinyint not null default (0),
fat tinyint not null default (0),
humidity tinyint not null default (0) ,
minerals tinyint not null default (0),
constraint PK_id_materialPriceAndStandard primary key (id),
constraint UQ_materialName_materialPriceAndStandard unique (materialName), 
constraint CHECK_totlaMineralAmount check 
(carbohydrate + protein + fat + humidity + minerals =100 ))
```

total amount of 5 fields in material table shall not exceed 100.

in C# i get this exception when the user enter amount that excceds 100:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint         
"CHECK_totalMineralAmount_materialPrice".
The conflict occurred in database "secaloFormula", table "dbo.materialPrice"
```

an this is the code that connects to database and call the stored procedure :

```
public void addMaterial()
    {
        string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["secaloFormulaCS"].ToString(); 
        using(SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConString))
        using(SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("spAddMaterial",sqlCon))
        {
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("materialName", MaterialName); 
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("unitPrice",Price);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("carbohydrate",Carbohydrtate);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("proterin", Proterin); 
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("fat",Fat); 
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("humidity", Humadity); 
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("minerals",Minerlas);
            sqlCon.Open();
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlCon.Close();
            sqlCon.Dispose(); 
        }
    }
```

how can i handle this exception, to alert the user when inserted amount exceeds 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try 
{
   sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
   // the error should be in the Ex
}
```

[SqlException Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

See the link.
That error is probably in ex.Errors.

With a using I don't think you need to Dispose but I doubt it hurts anything

Comment: your are right , the problem is i read many tutorials from many sources , which leads to a non-standard code!. but how can i learn to write code like a pro ?

Comment: Read a book.  For .NET I like Troelsen from Apress.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking constraints in your business logic rather than relying on the database to reject any invalid messages. If you're dead-set on using constraints for business rules, you can try/catch the ExecuteNonQuery and return the exception that is thrown.